# SPSS REPEAT: How do i use the stand-in-variable as part of variable name?

Tags: string, spss, recode

I'm using SPSS 20. 
In my dataset is a list of string variables which I want to recoded into numeric. Originally I wanted them to be recoded into themselves. 
I realize that this is not possible as SPSS runs through the dataset casewise and one variable can only have one type at a time. 
So I want them to be recoded into new variables but with the suffix `_rec`.

```
DO REPEAT var = var_1 var_2 ... var_n.
  RECODE var (CONVERT) INTO var_rec.
END REPEAT.
```

But this creates only one new variable `var_rec` not several new ones.

I also tried to programme a workaround:

```
COMPUTE Job_2
STRING Job(A20)
    DO REPEAT var = var_1 var_2 ... var_n.
COMPUTE var = Job. 
RECODE Job (CONVERT) INTO Job_2.
DELETE VARIABLES var.
COMPUTE var = Job_2.  
END REPEAT.
```

But this doesn't work because `DELETE VARIABLES` can not be used within a `DO REPEAT` loop.

So I'm back at my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say they (string variables) can't be recoded into themselves but they can using [`ALTER TYPE`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/mobile/#!/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_alter_type_overview.htm)

```
ALTER TYPE var_1 var_2 var_3 (F8.2).
```

Where F8.2 is a numeric variable of width 8 and 2 decimal points.

You can use `DO REPEAT` with multiple stand-in list of variables, like following:

```
DO REPEAT Old = var_1 var_2 var_3
    /New = var1_rec var2_rec var3_rec.
  RECODE Old (CONVERT) INTO New.
END REPEAT PRINT.
```

Which expanded out is the equivalent to:

```
RECODE var_1 (CONVERT) into var1_rec.
RECODE var_2 (CONVERT) into var2_rec.
RECODE var_3 (CONVERT) into var3_rec.
```

But if you are going to do that then you can do this within the `RECODE` command directly, something like this:

```
RECODE var_1 var_2 var_3 (CONVERT) INTO var1_rec var2_rec var3_rec.
```

Both methods assume the original variables are all string variables (of any and differing widths).

Take note of what exactly the [`CONVERT`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/mobile/#!/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/syn_recode_convert.html) function does, namely, taking a string variable (containing numeric values stored as string) and converting it to a numeric format variable. So the input variable is always a string and output numeric.

Comment: To your first suggestion: Wouldn't SPSS go through each variable-list and thus recode var_1, var_2 and va3_3 into var_1_rec(for example)? Only var_3 would be recoded at the end.

To your seccond suggestion: 
In order to do this RECODE needs all variables to be of the same type and width.

Comment: Updated post to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that DO REPEAT works this way.